# "uboot-tools" Install on Centos 7

Tags: centos, rpm, yum, u-boot

I require the use of the command `mkimage` in my Centos 7, 32-bit system.

I have attempted to install as root `uboot-tools` using the command `yum install ubool-tools` but this is not available.

Does anyone have any driving instructions on how I can install `uboot-tools` on my system please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason [`uboot-utils` is not available in EPEL7](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1155029). Get the SRPM from EPEL6 and rebuild it.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar, can you please provide rebuild instructions?

Comment: Apologies for the delay in accepting your answer.  I got sidetracked, and only got to test this this morning, and it worked a treat!

Comment: The Version for el6 is very old. You can use the Fedora source RPM (*.fc28.src.rpm). It worked for me to rebuild dtc and uboot-tools on CentOS 7 64-bit.